# Synchronization issues with Google Accounts and Gnome Online Accounts

Tags: gnome, sync, online-accounts

I'm currently GNOME 42.1 Ubuntu 22.04. I added Google account via the "Gnome Online Accounts". I can access GDrive but Calendars Contacts and Mail aren't synchronized. What can I do to make Sync work properly?
No data from GCalendars, GContacts  and Gmail is being shown.

Comment: Same problem for me, but when I create a new event in gnome calendar, it is synchronized with google calendar. Sync in the opposite direction is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the GDrive it basically means that you set your Google account correctly. Even if no events are showing in the calendar, what happens if you add a new event? Does it appear on your Google calendar (e.g., if you check it on the Google calendar's website or your smartphone)? If it does, you probably just hit the use limits imposed by Google (see, e.g., https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en). If you try again later (or tomorrow), you should see your Gnome calendar and Gnome contacts correctly populated.

That's the same behavior I experienced yesterday on a fresh Arch installation. Today, everything's working fine.